# Redshift generate rows as many as value in another column

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

df

```
customer_code contract_code    product  num_products
    C0134        AB01245        toy_1        4 
    B8328        EF28421        doll_4       2
```

I would like to transform this table based on the integer value in column num_products and generate a unique id for each row:

Expected_df

```
unique_id  customer_code contract_code     product      num_products
      A1           C0134        AB01245        toy_1        1 
      A2           C0134        AB01245        toy_1        1
      A3           C0134        AB01245        toy_1        1
      A4           C0134        AB01245        toy_1        1
      A5           B8328        EF28421        doll_4       1
      A6           B8328        EF28421        doll_4       1
```

- unique_id can be any random characters as long as I can use a count(distinct) on it later on.
  I read that `generate_series(1,10000) i` is available in later versions of Postgres but not in Redshift

Comment: `generate_series()` is available in Amazon Redshift, but it only runs on the Leader Node, meaning that it cannot be used in a query that accesses table data. It can be used to generate tables, but cannot be joined with existing tables. You could create a table of numbers and join against it instead.

Comment: any tips how I can create a table of numbers as many as the value inside a column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a recursive CTE to generate the series of number.  Then join this with you data to produce the extra rows.  I used row_number() to get the unique_id in the example below.

This should meet you needs or at least give you a start:

```
create table df (customer_code varchar(16),
                 contract_code varchar(16),
                 product varchar(16),
                 num_products int);

insert into df values
('C0134', 'AB01245', 'toy_1', 4),
('B8328', 'EF28421', 'doll_4', 2);

with recursive nums (n) as 
( select 1 as n
  union all
  select n+1 as n
  from nums 
  where n < (select max(num_products) from df) )
select row_number() over() as unique_id, customer_code, contract_code, product, num_products 
from df d
left join nums n
on d.num_products >= n.n;
```

SQLfiddle at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d829b/12

Comment: be careful, the solution will generate a row even if num_products=0